# Trying to pass a json string into ActionResult view from ActionAsPdf using rotativa

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, rotativa

So I have a controller that builds a pdf using several views, each view builds a specific section of the pdf.

I am passing pdfdata which is a json string that contains all the data the views need into ActionAsPdf like this

```
private byte[] CreateCertificatePart(CertificatePart part, string pdfdata)
    {
        var customSwitches = string.Format(
            "--print-media-type " +
            "--margin-top 10mm " +
            "--margin-bottom 10mm " +
            "--margin-left 10mm " +
            "--margin-right 10mm " +
            "--encoding utf-8 " +
            "--minimum-font-size 11 " +
            "--zoom 1.0 " +
            "--disable-smart-shrinking"
        );

        var viewname = part.ToString();
        var pdfResult = new ActionAsPdf(viewname,pdfdata) { CustomSwitches = customSwitches };
        var pdfBytes = pdfResult.BuildFile(ControllerContext);            

        return pdfBytes;
    }
```

Then the Action result calls the razor view which gets converted to pdf bytes by the ActionAsPdf.

```
public ActionResult CertificateBody(string pdfdata)
    {
        var data = new PdfData();

        try
        {
            data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PdfData>(pdfdata);

            return View(data.PdfBodyName, data.CertModel);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AppInsightLog.LogError(ex, $"NewCertificateBody{data.CertModel.Schedule.QuoteReference}");
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400, "NewCertificateBody");
        }
    }
```

The problem is pdfData is always null! this was a very long json string in CreateCertificatePart. I tried passing a model originally but that was also null, which is why I am trying to pass a string instead thinking that would be ok.

Its ok if I pass a very simple string like "hello" or an integer, so I could pass an ID but I do not want to make a database call in the action result method.. because then I will make the same call several times.

CreateCertificatePart is recursive but all the different views need the same model which is PdfData.

Thanks

Comment: If you are referring to this line `data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PdfData>("");
` then you should change it to `data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PdfData>(pdfdata);
`

Comment: Ah no, that is not the problem. The issue is that pdfdata is null.

Comment: Where are you calling this method `CertificateBody`?

Comment: I should have made clearer that the variable in CreateCertficiatePart method viewname is "CertificateBody" so it knows to call that action/view.

Comment: Ultimately is there any way of passing a model into ActionAsPdf?? it seems to reject all models and only allows a query string, but my string would be very long! as I am passing a big json structure